# How do I post firebase data into an xcode project's UItableview, and display that data in a game leaderboard format?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I made a small pong-style game in xcode (written in swift), this game is linked to a firebase realtime database, which collects user data aswell as stores their scores under the users UID and name. I am trying to figure out how to display this data (names and scores) in a UITableView within my project to give the user a leaderboard. I understand I can do this with GameCenter, but for sake of future manipulation I would like to know how to do this without using GameCenter.

I have read from some sources that I would need an array in a custom .swift file, then need to refer to that array in my UITableView file. If this is accurate information, how would I put data from a firebase realtime database in an array to refer to? If this is not true, what is the best way to make a leaderboard from firebase data?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to query for the leaderboard data from Firebase and than parse that into an array. You can query Firebase using their SDK.

You should get a database reference using

```
var ref: DatabaseReference! 
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

And then query.

```
ref.child(<path to leaderboard>).queryOrdered(byChild: <score path>).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with{ (snapshot) in
 //parse here
}
```

And save into an array.

Comment: Im new to coding, so pardon my ignorance. But how would i parse that query into an array?

Comment: @LukeNas there is great documentation at this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write